# Запретить выбор одинаковых элементов в разных QComboBox'ах

Tags: qt

Имеется 4 QComboBox'а с одинаковым списком параметров внутри: `параметр1 параметр2 параметр3 ...`. Заполняются QComboBox'ы следующим образом:

```
foreach(quint8 keys, mapDataComboBox.keys())
{
    comboBox1->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(keys), keys);
    comboBox2->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(keys), keys);
    comboBox3->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(keys), keys);
    comboBox4->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(keys), keys);
}
```

В mapDataComboBox собственно лежит этот список параметров. Каким образом запретить выбирать в разных QComboBox'ах одинаковые параметры? Например, если в первом QComboBox'е выбран `параметр2`, то во всех остальных QComboBox'ах его нельзя было выбрать, во втором QComboBox'е выбираем `параметр4`, то в остальных нельзя было выбрать уже `параметр4` и `параметр2`. Если в первом QComboBox'е выбрать `параметр1`, то `параметр2` должен стать доступен для выбора в остальных QComboBox'ах, а `параметр1` наоборот недоступен.

Answer (score 1):

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMap>
#include <QVariant>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QMap<quint8, QString> mapDataComboBox;
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    QVariant c1, c2, c3, c4; // Здесь будут храниться освобожденные данные
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void handleComboChange(int);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

//Заполняем примерный MAP
    mapDataComboBox.insert(1, "FIRST");
    mapDataComboBox.insert(2, "SECOND");
    mapDataComboBox.insert(3, "THIRD");
    mapDataComboBox.insert(4, "FOURTH");

//Заполняем комбобоксы
    foreach (quint8 key, mapDataComboBox.keys()) {
        ui->comboBox->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(key), key);
        ui->comboBox_2->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(key), key);
        ui->comboBox_3->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(key), key);
        ui->comboBox_4->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(key), key);
    }

// Текущий элемент каждого комбобокса = -1
    foreach (QObject *ob, ui->centralWidget->children()) {
        if(ob->inherits("QComboBox")){
            static_cast<QComboBox*>(ob)->setCurrentIndex(-1);
        }
    }

//Коннектим сигналы комбобоксов к одному слоту
    connect(ui->comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(handleComboChange(int)));
    connect(ui->comboBox_2, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(handleComboChange(int)));
    connect(ui->comboBox_3, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(handleComboChange(int)));
    connect(ui->comboBox_4, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(handleComboChange(int)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::handleComboChange(int)
{
    QComboBox *senderCombo = static_cast<QComboBox *>(sender());// Получили отправителя сигнала

//Получаем освобождаемые данные
    QVariant *previous;

    if(senderCombo->objectName() == "comboBox"){
        previous = &c1;
    }
    if(senderCombo->objectName() == "comboBox_2"){
        previous = &c2;
    }
    if(senderCombo->objectName() == "comboBox_3"){
        previous = &c3;
    }
    if(senderCombo->objectName() == "comboBox_4"){
        previous = &c4;
    }


    foreach (QObject *ob, ui->centralWidget->children()) {
        if(ob->inherits("QComboBox") && ob->objectName() != senderCombo->objectName()){
            QComboBox *box = static_cast<QComboBox *>(ob);
            box->removeItem(box->findData(senderCombo->currentData()));//Удаляем из всех остальных комбобоксов занимаемые данные
            if(*previous != QVariant()){
                box->addItem(mapDataComboBox.value(static_cast<quint8>((*previous).toInt())), static_cast<quint8>((*previous).toInt()));// И добавляем освободившееся
            }
        }
    }
    *previous=senderCombo->currentData();
}
```

Comment: А зачем нужно `*previous=senderCombo->currentData();`? `previous` ведь только в функции объявлен

Comment: @gil9red с помощью оператора разыменования(*) мы получаем доступ к данным за указателем. В данном случае получаем доступ к одной из переменных `c`

Comment: понял, но кажется, что можно сделать проще